# Issue in connecting database in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am getting the following error while creating a database in MongoDB while connecting to the server:

> not authorized on careerassistant to execute command { create: "jobfields", lsid: { id: UUID("c1af6f79-3772-4d10-a536-0d62656ebcbb") }, $db: "careerassistant" }
> anyone suggest how to solve this.. thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the contents of `mongod.conf`? and where does this MongoDB host at?

Comment: Try running a `connectionStatus` command to see what permissions that account has.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.